# Should I use executeUpdate or execute to delete a row with Anorm?

Tags: scala, anorm

I'm using Anorm and I wonder which solution is the best to use when I have to delete only one row (for instance here I know that the field `eventId` is unique).

```
SQL("DELETE FROM events WHERE eventId = {eventId}")
   .on('eventId -> eventId)
   .executeUpdate()
```

And test if **the returned value is 1** or, use this version with `execute()`:

```
 SQL("DELETE FROM events WHERE eventId = {eventId}")
    .on('eventId -> eventId)
    .execute()
```

and test if **the returned value is true** ?

Is there any difference ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The boolean from `.execute` doesn't indicate whether it's successful, but whether it has executed a query or an update.

Using `.executeUpdate`, the result is the count of updated/deleted rows. If the goal is to check whether something has been altered by execution, then `.executeUpdate` is useful.